# Delegate with predefined parameter

Tags: c#, delegates

I need to pass pointer to a function as a parameter. It looks like this:

```
void f(Action<String> a);
```

But what if caller knows which string will be used. And he's always knows it. Sure i can add one more parameter, but this is not cool.

Can i somehow create delegate with predefined parameter? Thanks.

EDIT:

As workaround i can do like that

```
void f(Action<String> a, String s)
{
    a(s);
}

...
f(_delegate, "string");
```

Comment: `() => a("some string")` will be an `Action`, it's the the most simple way.

Comment: You could do `f(u => a(myString))`, but then whatever string `f` was passing to `a` will get ignored and that seems wrong.

Comment: @Spo1ler That's an `Action`, but it's not an `Action<string>`.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "Sure i can add one more parameter" - to what? The method? The lambda expression? Do you want the delegate to *validate* the string that's passed?

Comment: "caller knows which string will be used" -- which caller? The caller of the delegate `a`? Or the caller of the function `f()`? In what scenario does the latter even make sense? I.e. why do you have a method `f()` that would pass a string to a delegate where the string `f()` would pass is already know by the implementation of the delegate method? Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows exactly what you mean.

Comment: I dont understand? You want a delegate with default parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Spo1ler commented, pass an `Action` instead of `Action<string>`:

```
void f(Action a)
{
    a();
}
...
f(() => _delegate("string"));
```